# Jaxb DateTime without timezone

Tags: java, xml, datetime, jaxb, jodatime

I'm trying to map a xml DateTime element using jaxb so that it does not care about timezone information at all. Either by rejecting the input, or by treating it as server default timezone. e.g.

```
<dateTime>2011-01-01T06:00:00-04:00:00</dateTime>
```

would be treated the same as

```
<dateTime>2011-01-01T06:00:00</dateTime>
```

Right now GregorianCalendar automatically converts any dateTime with timezone information to GregorianCalendar object, so I don't know what the original input was. Can anyone shine some light on this? I'm open to use other dateTime types other than GregorianCalendar too, is there a graceful way to use `org.joda.time.DateTime` object with jaxb/xml maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is there a built-in Java `DateTime` type? Not 'til JSR 310, at any rate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a useful [post on Joda and JAXB](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html) from Blaise Doughan using an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` which you should be able to use to convert the time format.